# Substitute a character column with numbers

Tags: r, gsub

I have a df like this:

```
df <- 
ID                  ID2
Subject 10010-001   NA
Subject 20010-002   NA
```

I want to get rid of anything before the `-` and keep the number. The ouput should be like this.

```
df <-
ID                  ID2
Subject 10010-001   001
Subject 20010-002   002
```

I tried to use `gsub` but still didn't get it right yet. This is what I have tried.

`df$ID2 <- as.numeric(gsub("Subject \\d+-","",as.character(df$ID)))`

I am using RStudio.

Comment: Your regex is fine. Take a look at the result of `gsub("Subject \\d+-","",as.character(df$ID))` and then consider `as.numeric("001")`

Comment: It seems to me you want [`df$ID2 <- sub(".*-", "", df$ID)`](https://ideone.com/rsrJOO).

Comment: @thelatemail Yep, you are right! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with strsplit as well, if you are not up for regex.

```
do.call('rbind',lapply(strsplit(c("Subject 10010-001", "Subject 20010-002"),"-"),`[[`,2))
```

Here strsplit will split your data with "-" , then we fetch the second item from the strsplit output using `lapply` and `[[`. The final output can be put into a column wise representation using `do.call` , you may choose `unsplit` over here also . The above output is a matrix with character data. You can use  data.frame to put it in the desired form.

or **better** as suggested by @thelatemail

```
 sapply(strsplit(c("Subject 10010-001", "Subject 20010-002"),"-"),`[[`,2)
```

Here the same logic is applied but it is much less cumbersome as you don't have to bind anything, since we are using `sapply` instead of `lapply`.

**Your existing regex seems to be correct** , the only check is I think you should n't use `as.numeric` over there if you want **00** in the front.